# Check if session is set or not, and if not create one?

Tags: php, session

I want to check if a session is currently set, and if so do allow the page to run as normal (do nothing) if not create a session.

I had a look at another SO question, in which the following code was posted:

```
if ( empty( $_SESSION['login'] )) { } else { }
```

Would the easiest way to do this be to set something like `$_SESSION['a']` for each session, and then run `if(empty($_SESSION['a']))` to check if a session exists?

Then again, can you use a session variable without invoking session_start() in the first place, thus making it obsolete (I tried this yesterday, as an echo though, not an if statement to check that a variable was carrying through without realizing that session_start() needed to be invoked before I could echo the variable).

There's probably an easy way that's oft used, I just can't seem to find it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`session_id()` returns the string identifying the current session. If a session hasn't been initialized, it will return an empty string.

```
 if(session_id())
 {
      // session has been started
 }
 else
 {
      // session has NOT been started
      session_start();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :). I'll accept after that 10 minute timer goes away.

Comment: A further improvement - you don't need to check to see if the string is false - use the return of `session_id()` as the test itself; empty strings are "falsey" values, meaning that `''` will evaluate to false in the `if` statement.